# iOS: Animating text position of UIButton doesn't work

Tags: ios, animation, uibutton

I want to have the text of the button 'go away' when pressing a 'wrong answer' button.

In my problem-demo code, my project has two buttons, one with outlet 'myBtn' without any action, and one with `TouchUpInside` action. The action handler looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)goPressed:(UIButton*)sender {

//UILabel *lbl = self.myBtn.titleLabel;
UILabel *lbl = sender.titleLabel;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     lbl.center = CGPointMake(lbl.center.x-60, lbl.center.y);
                     lbl.alpha = 0;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

I am trying to animate two properties: 'alpha' to go from 1 to 0, and position of text to move 60 points to the left.

If I uncomment the first "UILAbel" line and comment the second, then pressing the button runs a nice animation in the second button.

But if I leave the code as it appears, trying to animate the text of the pressed button itself, the alpha is animating fine, but the position is not changing.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Try with sender.currenttitle

Comment: Why not just animate the whole button / set the text to ""?

Comment: CurrentTitle is NSString so I cannot animate its position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this kind of problem occurring on iOS7. Animations that worked fine inside an IBAction, don't work on iOS7. I had to move all my animation code to a different method and call the selector after a delay. Your code will work fine if you do this -

```
- (IBAction) goPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
[self performSelector:@selector(animateButton:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void) animateButton:(UIButton *) button{
UILabel *lbl = button.titleLabel;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     lbl.center = CGPointMake(lbl.center.x-60, lbl.center.y);
                     lbl.alpha = 0;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kedar. It works like a charm! even with a delay of 0.05. 
It is interesting because adding a delay of even several seconds to the animation itself did not solve the problem...

Comment: @Kedar is this a bug? because this helps me don't even know why =/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is mixing up the `UIButton` with the `UILabel`.

The method parameter `(UIButton*)sender` is referencing a `UIButton` in this case.  The reason `UILabel *lbl = sender.titleLabel;` doesn't work is because the `sender` is a `UIButton` reference.  To access the label object, you must reference the the `UILabel` embedded in the `UIButton` via the hirarchy `sender > UIButton > UILabel`.

So the code you should use is:

```
UIButton *button = sender;
UILabel *lbl = sender.titleLabel;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                  delay:0.0
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
             animations:^{
                 lbl.center = CGPointMake(lbl.center.x-60, lbl.center.y);
                 lbl.alpha = 0;
             }
         completion:nil];
}
```

The reason why the code as it appears behaves strangly is because `alpha` is a property of both `UIButton`s and `UILabel`s.  So it will work even if you are incorrectly refenrencing the `sender`.

Comment: Thank you for the response Andrew, but I do not get your point. I am not confusing anything in my code. The sender is a UIButton, and I am taking its titleLabel correctly. I will check Kedar's solution and report shortly